# How to resolve the Storyboard's warnings on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

```
Trailing(Leading) constraint is missing, which may cause overlapping with other views
```

My storyboard: (just put 2 labels and their constraints)

[image: storyboard]

[image]

What is the best way to avoid these warnings?

Comment: you are providing few constraints which are not needed or missing, and even if you want them they require more attention, so click on these warning at it will show you fix option, check what it does? else try applying proper constraints.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Give **Trailing** to Hello, Label with World! label like below image give **Constant** 8 (What minimum gap you need) to Trailing constraint and change Relation to **Grater than or Equal**.

[image]

Comment: Did not helped, warning is still saying the same...

Comment: @MaksimKniazev are you facing same issue?

Comment: Yes, I had to remove all constraints and added them again. Seems like it worked

Comment: @MaksimKniazev Great...!! Happy that worked for you :)